# Is it OK to offer help/mentorship to users beyond the current question?

Tags: discussion, comments

I saw in a question that after a correct answer, the asker thanked the answered:

> Thanks a lot @answerer and Thanks for given Note :-)

To that, the answerer replied:

> let me know for further guidance. In case if you need any help. :)

About which the asker was very happy:

> Sure @answerer May I need a lot of doubt in future, surely I will ask you, Thanks :-)

Is offering this kind of help acceptable/allowed?

**For reference**

[image]

Comment: _How directly let him know for any guidance in Stack Overflow?_ you cant unless you can get in a chat room with them.. New users are known to ping answerers in their old answers for help but these comments are just flagged for deletion and a lot of users dont welcome it.

Comment: Previously, we have a specific flag for those comments: [Too chatty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181076/when-should-the-too-chatty-flag-for-comments-be-used), which is now united into "no longer needed".

Comment: More like 'too creepy' or 'too stalky':(

Comment: That means the comment is technically valid, right? @SurajRao

Comment: No.. its noise and can be flagged for deletion. It is not asking for clarification or giving any info

Comment: SO, can I remove this question? @SurajRao

Comment: I edited the text a bit. If you're unhappy with something, feel free to edit again (or roll back, although the original version does need some clarification!)

Comment: @downvoter please explain I have written a note *If any experts can say in the comment which is this question is so boring or it has broken Stack Overflow Meta rule then I will remove this question ASAP.*

Comment: @downboater, for now, I'm not able to delete my question, please vote for close

Comment: Never mind downvotes on Meta, we all get them. Downvoting is more fast and loose here, you don't lose any reputation from the downvotes. There is nothing wrong with your question other than that it was already asked - for a non-English expert it is difficult to find the right words -  and it was a bit difficult to understand what exactly you meant. I'd just leave the question standing, no one will hold it against you in the future.

Comment: I downvoted because I say "no" to *Is offering this kind of help acceptable/allowed?*. In the context of Stack Overflow of course, outside of it you're free to do as you please. I am far from a fan of people latching on to specific "heroes", that needs to be nipped in the bud for everyone's comfort. Otherwise everyone and their grandmother would be pinging a certain singular popular user if they have a Java or .NET question.

Answer (score 6):

Offers of mentorship *in comments* are absolutely allowed under the site's rules. It's not up to us to police users making connections among each other. *Asking* for such mentorship is never ok, though.

If a user offers mentoring and help, the implication is usually that they have a publicly visible non-Stack Overflow way to reach them (like E-Mail). The asker would contact them that way. This can not happen on Stack Overflow - there is no private message system, nor is the site intended for such communication.

Directly approaching users on Stack Overflow to direct their attention towards a specific question without such a previous offer of mentorship is highly discouraged.